# Microsoft Graph: OpenWorkbookTooLarge – any way around this?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When calling the *createSession* or *workbook/worksheets* endpoint I'm getting the following error:

```
{
"error": {
"code": "OpenWorkbookTooLarge",
"message": "Service Unavailable.",
"innerError": {
"request-id": "c997d356-c343-44bb-b49b-fc03d7482f75",
"date": "2018-11-28T22:58:21"
}
}
}
```

The spreadsheet in OneDrive has only one sheet with 16 columns and about 160,000 rows. Is that too large to work with? That would be very disappointing...

Answer (score 1):

Excel Online have file size limit, based on the [docs](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_online_support_blog/2016/05/26/excel-online-open-large-workbooks-in-the-browser/) and the error you get, you have trigger the limitation, maybe not file size but other one.

> Workbooks that exceed 10 megabytes (MB) cannot be viewed in Excel
>   Online from within Microsoft SharePoint Online.

For none-dev user, they can use the PowerBI/Local Excel/PivotTable as workaround.

For devolper, there are no workaround now.

Answer (score 1):

Jeez, it's even worse: 5MB
That's sad, really.

[image]